# Third party API returns httpresponsemessage. Can someone help me to understand how to extract data out of httpresponsemessage and return generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public async Task<>GetLandProperty(string num)
{
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _httpClient.BaseAddress+relativeurl);
// added required headers here.
 var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Now here  response is `httpresponsemessage`. I don't understand how to extract data out of response and deserialize it. Probably I can create class, fetch response's content and deserialise it but what to do if it return failure response or exception. how to return generic type in this case.

Comment: you can see the response in browser console network tab . see the structure of response and then work accordingly

Comment: yes but what should i return incase not success. how to return generic return type

Comment: you can return like this `return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to your api code. You can catch the exception information and return different information by setting the **`HttpStatusCode` of `HttpResponseMessage`** in the api side.

In the `GetLandProperty` method, you can set the return type to **object** to return different content.

Determine the returned content by judging the status of `IsSuccessStatusCode` of response. If the status is true, use the type returned by deserialize and return the corresponding object. If it is false, return the response directly.

```
public async Task<object> GetLandProperty()
    {
        Product product = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseString);
                product = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(responseString);
                return product;
            }
            return response;

        } 
    }
```

My api code:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Product persona = _context.Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DataID == id);
        if (persona != null)
        {
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            response.Content = new StringContent("error message");
            return response;
        }

    }
```

### Update

Another method to receive GetLandProperty method returned content:

```
   public async Task<object> CallTest()
        {
            var obj = await GetLandProperty();
            if(obj is Product)
            {
                Product product= (Product)obj;
                // save data to db

            }
            else
            {
                //do other operations
                return obj;
            }


        }
```

Here is the test result by postman:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I can return object but when i consume this GetLandProperty, it will either return products or response. when it returns product i need to store it into DB and when it returns response i need to do something else, how can i know what it return on consuming

Comment: @Disha, so you mean you has another method to receive the content returned by the GetLandProperty method to determine whether to perform a storage operation or other operations?  If so, `you can determine whether the content returned by GetLandProperty is of the Product type`, if it is, then perform the storage operation, otherwise perform other. Specific operation, I have updated my answer.

Comment: just one question, if third party api does not return successful response, in other words lets suppose if it returns status code 401 and message "unauthorise" then how to handle this scenario? shall i  throw exception (if yes but then it can return anything other than 401, how to do that). shall i create custom exception and throw, but throwing exception is performance hit right? or any other suggestion?

Comment: @Disha, If your purpose is only to store data to the database in case of success, as long as the status code returned by the api is not 200, then you can return any error message you want the client to receive. In the `CallTest` method, when `obj` cannot be converted into object (that is, an error message is returned), directly return obj, that is, the current error message.I have updated my post.

Comment: here, In CallTest() method, if obj is Product type , saving it into database plus  need to return same saved object. if obj is not Product type then whatever response i am getting from GetLandAndProperty() (statuscode 403, reasonPhrase- 'forbidden') i need to send back to client with custom message (like- statuscode 403, message- not subscribed.) or how to do this? plus this callTest Method called by another method which returns IActionResult (i am using asp.net core 3.1) where i am not able to return statuscodes in function app.

Comment: can i build something generic where if GetLandAndProperty does not return any successful response, based on statuscode i can customise messages and then send back to client, how to do that?

Comment: one more thing, if GetLandAndProperty return (401 and unauthorised) if i returns same response to client then my api( which client call and that api internally calls third party api (GetLandAndProperty)) return 200 status code but returns response  which GetLandAndProperty returned, is it okay? or myapi should also return 401 which GetLandAndProperty returns?

Comment: @Disha, From the dynamic diagram I gave you, httpresponse status will display the specific error code. Of course, you can use `if or switch` judgment to return different error information according to different error codes after an error occurs, `but this is not flexible`. Do you need to add all possible error codes to the judgment? If you only aim at several special error codes, it may be possible. And I think what kind of message will be returned finally depends on your needs, you can decide completely for yourself .

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure whats the question.
To get response data

```
  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and to desriazile it

```
var json= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks able to desearilize.